# How can i use special characters (ä,ü..) in LaTeX package qrcode

Tags: latex

Code with Vcard informations in it. How can i use sepcial german characters like ä,ü, and so on. My file is saved under utf-8 encoding. This minimal example gives error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[]{qrcode}

\begin{document}

\qrcode{
BEGIN:VCARD\?
VERSION:4.0\?
N:Do;Jon;;Dr.\?
FN:Dr. Jon Do\?
ORG:Firma; Überirdische Firma\?
END:VCARD
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230862/why-are-accented-capital-letters-not-well-decoded-in-qrcode

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. But i do not know why it works..
Adding this line `VERSION:3.0\?` fixed the problem.